# What's the limit of $\frac{1 - P(B)}{1 - P(B|A)}$ when P(B) approaches 1

Tags: probability, limits

The setup is pretty simple. I know that in the event of P(B) = 1, the fraction is 0 / 0.

However, if we take a limit point of view, does the expression approaches infinity or 0?

naively, P(B | A)  = # of A and B  / # of A

I am having the following thought:
if we use binomial distribution,
Expected # A and B =  # of B * P(A)
Expected # A =  N * P(A)

so roughly Expected ( P(B | A) ) = P(B)    (of course, the 2 count is not independent, so we probably cannot take a ratio this way)

and the limit of the fraction is about 1 on average.

Comment: Not much can be said: If $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, we get $0$; if $A$ and $B$ are independent we get $1$. It should be possible to give examples for where the limit is equal to anything nonnegative, I'd guess.

Comment: Rewrite is as $\frac {P(B^c)}{P(B^c|A)}$. Could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be a random variable with $P(x\in [a,b])=b-a$ when $0\leq a\leq b\leq 1.$ Let $A\equiv (0\leq x\leq \frac {1}{2}).$ For $n\in N$ let $a_n, b_n \in (0,\frac {1}{2})$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0=\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n.$ Let $B_n\equiv (x\in [0,\frac {1}{2}-a_n]\cup [\frac {1}{2},1-b_n]).$ Then $\lim_{n\to \infty}P(B_n)=1$ while $$(1-P(B))/(1-P(B|A))=(a_n+b_n)/a_n=1+(a_n/b_n)$$ which may fail to converge as $n\to \infty,$ or may converge to any member of $[1,\infty).$

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation!